# How to Install "RarArchive" on MacbookPro?

Tags: php

Anyone tried installing "

```
RarArchive
```

on their macbookpro? I tried installing but I got this error

```
.1.13/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -DRARDLL -DSILENT -Wno-write-strings -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/rar/unrar -DZEND_COMPILE_DL_EXT=1 -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/rar/rar_stream.c -MMD -MF rar_stream.dep -MT rar_stream.lo  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/rar_stream.o
/private/tmp/pear/temp/rar/rar_stream.c:170:23: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type 'uint64' (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
                                        self->file_size, self->cursor);
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/private/tmp/pear/temp/rar/rar_stream.c:787:58: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 1, have 2
                        zend_string *arc_str = zend_resolve_path(tmp_archive, tmp_arch_len);
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [rar_stream.lo] Error 1
rolling back 454 file operations
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Cause I'm trying to solve this warning on my PHP IDE warning.[image]

Thank you!

I tried installing via pecl but it did not work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry, I was able to fix this issue by just downgrading the PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by downgrading the PHP version from 8.1 to 8 and all the error is gone.

Hopefully, this will help others as well.